# The top menu has moved to the left

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

The top menu has moved to the left. I checked in two different browsers.

[image]

Comment: They are updating the site theme, expect a few issues until it is up https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18038/ask-ubuntu-new-site-theme-coming-soon

Comment: Reproduced, but I think we'll just have to wait it out for now

Comment: @MarkKirby In this post, “Update the site” is scheduled for “Late July” – *did* they start updating the site already? The post is two days old and says they first want to “Collect and respond to feedback from this post”…

Comment: @dessert IDK, I just assumed based on the fact thy said they would remove the Ubuntu links and that is what seems to cause this issue, for me it overlaps the main bar now. If we are not getting the new theme yet, it could still be related to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312501/new-global-preferences-keyboard-shortcuts-and-sticky-topbar either way, I think we just have to live with it for a bit.

Comment: Whoops, I broke that. Looking into a fix.

Comment: A Windows screenshot? So sad. :( :P

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I use two operating systems (Windows 10 Pro  /Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Comment: @VladSpirin yeah, mine was just a joke. :) I browse Ask Ubuntu using macOS sometimes. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry about that. I broke this while [rolling out support for fixed topbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312501/new-global-preferences-keyboard-shortcuts-and-sticky-topbar) across all network sites.

There's no graceful way to make this work right now with the custom bar in play as well. Not without a fair amount of effort, at any rate. Since Ask Ubuntu is going to get [a new theme soon](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18038/ask-ubuntu-new-site-theme-coming-soon), I'm deploying a change now to defer fixed topbar support until that time.