# Ask Ubuntu new site theme is live

Tags: discussion, design

We rolled out the new site theme for Ask Ubuntu. It is now live.

### What new theme?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes)  (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background).

### Your help needed

You are one of the first sites to get a new, unified theme. I [previously posted the designs for theme](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18038/ask-ubuntu-new-site-theme-coming-soon) in meta. The feedback given to that post was considered prior to rolling out the theme. Please help us look for issues/bugs and post the details (including images where needed) as an answer below.

If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback. If you have issues with any functionality that is unrelated to the new theme, then please post a new question.

Comment: Observation: Something didn't play nice when I refreshed the page, it ended up blowing up my Chrome and crashing it.  Had to purge my entire cache and profile (and cookies and other data) just to get Chrome to stop misbehaving just with this site.  Not sure if Chrome barfed or if some remnant from old was still drifting around or not...

Comment: I really don't like having only 4 topics on the frontpage. And NO I can not get better eyesight.

Comment: @Rinzwind It would be helpful if you could post more details as an answer and include details of how your browser is set up (zoom, etc) along with images of what you're seeing. Thanks.

Comment: The new theme looks great. I will look for any bugs.

Comment: When I click ask a question, the boxes are already filled in with a previous post.

Comment: Personally I like the old theme better. Thanks to devs for giving us the option to revert back almost all changes. The left bar is using double space than before, disabled it. I don't need the sticky search bar, disabled it too. I feel both of them waste space and steal focus on my 14" display. Not only the orange askubuntu bar totally lost it's functionality but also it got wider!! I used to use it to go to newest questions from anywhere. Though I can now use the hamburger menu on top left, it always requires 1 more click. Will be happy if devs give an option to revert back to old theme.

Comment: Missing the old theme.. Feeling cramped in new theme, even after removing left-bar.

Answer (score 29):

I can't tell I'm on Ask Ubuntu once I scroll past our logo.

I know there *are* small visual cues, but the generic `.top-bar` completely steals my focus and I think I'm on "Stack Exchange". SO has overcome this problem quite simply by displacing the network branding. Why can't we all do that?

- Get rid of the `<header>`, like SO has
- Replace the Stack Exchange logo, like SO has
- Colour the main bar, like SO has

A few clicks with the Firefox dev tools, gives me something like this. Obviously the text colour needs tweaking to something darker or lighter for contrast.

[image]

I'd be really surprised if the other sites with strong branding didn't want the same, or to de-sticky the distracting header.

Comment: Good idea but I like the [Josh’s proposal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18123/250300) better.

Comment: The header being sticky is already an option in your preferences, actually. :) You can make it unsticky whenever you like. https://askubuntu.com/users/preferences/449 :D

Answer (score 19):

Basically my only concern is that the orange header bar is so *huge*, and yet it doesn't do anything at all. It's as tall as an entire question!

I don't understand why Stack Overflow gets a unified header, but all the other sites are forced into having a second huge block of colour to house their logo.

I wrote some CSS to give AU a SO-esque unified header (the logo is off due to a horrible hack):

[image]

then I started really procrastinating and made an orange one too:

[image]

and honestly, I prefer either of those to the current design.

Comment: Most of the sites *want* a custom banner and are, in fact, quite disappointed in them being made shorter because it means less of the site's unique qualities are retained and it means the sites are less distinguishable from each other outside of the logo itself. Sites like AU don't have as much art as sites like [photography.se] or [scifi.se], so it's a different argument. I'm not sure if it's possible to meet the needs of both groups of sites.

Comment: Damn, this looks awesome, someone should make this a userstyle.

Answer (score 14):

Joe, I basically only have 1 issue: the vertical space where questions are shown. Example:

[image]

The main focus of the page should be the questions. Not the left pane, not the right pane and not the top. The 2 panes are fine. But the top is taking up too much space. I used to have 10 questions on my screen, now I see 6 (well I said 4 but my zoom is now also 1 less than it used to be).

From the questions upwards you have a block of white, orange and black with nothing. I believe it would be nicer with 1 "small" change: put "active" up to "month" next to "top questions" and "ask question". That would leave room for 2 maybe 3 questions extra.

---

Compared to the old version it would look like this:

[image]

To small for my eyes and far too much white space left and right.

Comment: We actually explored taking over the top bar with theming, but for the communities that have a ton of customization, it's yet _another thing_ that they lose. I'm a big fan of this direction though.

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [badges](/questions/tagged/badges) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Badge icons in the top bar are partially covered by the numbers (on the main site, not on Meta):

> [image]

(tested on Firefox and Safari on macOS)

---

Seems to be wider issue. Also happens on the profile page (`https://askubuntu.com/users/$id/$username`) in badges and tags:

> [image: badges and tags]

Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I can confirm on Firefox ESR 52.9.0 on main (askubuntu.com) site.

Comment: Confirming on Chrome Beta 69.0.3497.23. I'm pretty sure it was displaying fine yesterday, though.

Comment: This is also happening on Server Fault and Super User – seems to be a wider problem with the new theme.

Comment: @Josh, thanks, you're right. I've raised a bug report on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314038/295232).

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)  [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Visited question links are not differentiated by color.

Previously design had difference between `:active` and `:visited` CSS selectors for questions.

Without such difference it is difficult to determine visited questions by color.

Comment: I can confirm this on Main Site, but I cannot Confirm on Meta.

Comment: A fix for this has been merged and will go live after the next build.

Comment: Confirmed fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Suggestion to get rid of the huge but useless orange top bar ([post 1](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18119/3940), [post 2](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18123/3940)) and to keep us informed [we are on Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18120/3940) and not on another site:

1. Move the Ask Ubuntu logo to the left side menu
2. Remove the orange bar entirely
3. Move the search box  a bit to the right to align to the menu

[image]

Comment: This is a really interesting proposal. We aren't ignoring posts on this topic, but the change would be pretty major and are related to branding discussions we need to have internally. Please feel heard, but we won't be considering changes based on this feedback until this round of updates is completed across the network.

Comment: @JoeFriend thank you for your kind words. I wrote an [answer to the general meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314184/210600) for this, and also to better explain why it is an issue for me.

Comment: This looks nice but what about users who disabled the left sidebar like me?

Comment: @Melebius: That's a different story. AU logo to replace the Hamburger menu icon?

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The top-bar isn't sticky for me. It is sticky on U&L, Meta SE and Meta SO. I have custom styles set, but disabling those don't help with stickiness. I have tried toggling the stickiness preference in my AU preferences to no avail.

Comment: Yep. We need to update something to get that working. AU was "special" since it had the extra top bar in the old design. Should be working today.

Comment: @JoeFriend FWIW, it seems setting the toggle doesn't add the `_fixed` class to the top bar. But I guess that's the special-casing for AU that you guys are fixing. Hope to see it working soon.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoeFriend top bar still stick.  Left bar does, top bar doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, the behaviours is inconsistent. It is sticky on the preferences page itself if I toggle it there, but not elsewhere or otherwise. :/

Comment: @muru Should be working now.

Comment: @JoeFriend working on main, not on meta.

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed fixed, thanks @JoeFriend

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Just visited *Search* page ( https://askubuntu.com/search ).
Clicked *Advanced Search Tips* and was surprised with location of the tips.
They were opened below *Advanced Search Tips* link.

> [image: Advanced Search Tips table]

So it is impossible to read tip and apply it to the search bar in the same time.

Please move the table of tips to the right as it was before.

Answer (score 1):

Today I noticed the color around OP’s profile changed to the red from the blue being used across all SE sites I can think about, regardless of what their main color is.

[image: user profile screenshot]

When I first saw it (with another user’s profile), I thought: *He’s kinda blocked?*
No, it seems to be a feature of the new theme.

Well, AU uses a red-white theme, so why not? I guess I can get used to this. However, the tags and bounties still remain blue:

---

[image: screenshot of the featured questions]

as well as the frame around text areas:

[image: screenshot of a text area]

…and maybe other features I haven’t found yet. Shouldn’t the color theme be more consistent?