# Badges getting cut in half

Tags: bug, design, badges

Seems like the badges are getting cut in half. Attaching the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314038/badge-icons-partially-hidden-on-some-sites-with-the-new-design and https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18126/3940