# Why is the Search box close to invisible on Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange

Why is the search box (and button) in the top bar on Stack Exchange not visible at all times? I have been using Stack Exchange for months and only just found it by clicking randomly around the top of the screen.

An undesirable side-effect is users asking questions instead of finding previous answers via a search.

At least on grounds of inclusiveness (particularly for those of us with mediocre eyesight) this would be worth implementing.

Comment: If you use the site search for some time and compare the results to those from DuckDuckGo/Google (using `site:askubuntu.com`) you will likely find a reason why they are "hiding" the search bar ;-)

Comment: guntbert - I'm not sure what you mean - surely SE uses DDG or Google behind the scenes? It would be interesting to know whether searches on SE are tracked (Google) or untracked (DDG).

Comment: I do know what he means. Searching on google is -FAR- superior. Use `site: www.askubuntu.com {what you want to search}` and it will show anything from www.askubuntu.com. Works very well in finding duplicates ;) Example with the word "theme" https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=Krx3XJ3TKNGbjLsPztuq6AY&q=site%3A+www.askubuntu.com+theme&oq=site%3A+www.askubuntu.com+theme&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39.7124.7124..8005...0.0..0.44.44.1......0....1..gws-wiz.S0R0op094dk

Answer (score 3):

The design of the site is a global concept across all stackexchange sites.

See [Ask Ubuntu new site theme is live](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18114/ask-ubuntu-new-site-theme-is-live)  (and the closed [Ask Ubuntu new site theme coming soon](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18038/ask-ubuntu-new-site-theme-coming-soon) )

Important link from that points to the introduction of the changes: [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes)

There are no settings to change the color of the top bar though Oli made a comment in the 1st link where he used some client side alterations to get the orange back for the top bar.

Weird thing: gmail does the same. My search bar at the top is as dark as the rest when using a dark theme.

Comment: That discussion is interesting. Do you know if any issues have been addressed? For example I am now scrolled down to your reply and the Ask Ubuntu logo has scrolled off screen - it is no longer clear where we are.

I have looked for (but not found) a Stack Exchange preferences where I can alter the look of SE - does this exist?

Also what about an advanced search? We need to both find previous answers and avoid duplicating answered questions.

Comment: Oli made the same comment in one of the threads. And no I have not seen any updates on the theme after it got introduced (but that's not saying it did not happen ;)).